Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed! when using eas build
`eas build --profile preview --platform ios
failing again and again due to Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Failed to set up credentials.
Error: read ECONNRESET
I have installed the latest version of eas cli as suggested by other posts but it did not help.
Here is the list of globally installed packages:
corepack@0.17.0 eas-cli@8.0.0 expo-cli@6.3.10 npm@9.5.1
Work flow: expo managed
"expo": "~50.0.14",`
